# through exception in mvc on send email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email

I want to send email from an excel file.
When It get wrong email address it stop sending.
I want it send all email and at last show me wrong email that isn't able to send.
This my code for read Excel file:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(excel))
        {
            var src = excel;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Server.MapPath("~/") + src);

            if (fileExtension == ".xls" || fileExtension == ".xlsx")
            {
                string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/") + src;

                string excelConnectionString = string.Empty;
                excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                if (fileExtension == ".xls")
                {
                    excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
                    fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }
                else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                {
                    excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                    fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }
                OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
                excelConnection.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                dt = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                if (dt == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
                int t = 0;
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    excelSheets[t] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                    t++;
                }
                OleDbConnection excelConnection1 = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);


                string query = string.Format("Select * from [{0}]", excelSheets[0]);
                using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, excelConnection1))
                {
                    dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
                }
            }
            if (fileExtension.ToString().ToLower().Equals(".xml"))
            {
                string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/") + src;
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileLocation))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(fileLocation);
                }

                Request.Files["FileUpload"].SaveAs(fileLocation);
                XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(fileLocation);
                // DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(xmlreader);
                xmlreader.Close();
            }
```

And this is code for send email:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string excelname = "";

                if (lang == "1")
                {
                    excelname = "<div style='text-align:right;'>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() + "<br/>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString() + "</div>";
                }
                else
                {
                    excelname = "<div style='text-align:left;'>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() + "<br/>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString() + "</div>";
                }
                exceltotal = excelname + text + newslink + attach;
                //sender
                message = string.Format(body, img, exceltotal, title, prehead, senderemail);
                MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
                email.To.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString());
                email.From = new MailAddress(senderemail);
                email.Subject = maintitle;
                email.Body = message + makedelivey(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString(), maintitle);
                email.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                email.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient ssmtp = new SmtpClient();
                ssmtp.Host = server;
                ssmtp.Port = port;
                ssmtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                ssmtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderemail, senderpassword);
                ssmtp.EnableSsl = false;
                ssmtp.Send(email);
                exceltotal = "";
                message = "";
            }
```

It read a text file and add some value from excel or database base on user selection.

Comment: Which line of code sends the email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find line of code which sends email. But wherever you are sending the email inside the loop, make sure you enclose that code in `try` `catch` block. This ensures even if a mail send operation is failed, the error is handled and goes on with other mails. You can include your consolidate and formatting of failures issues in catch block.

```
   var consolidateErrors = string.Empty;
   for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
   {
      Try
       {
         //Mail sending logic here
       }
       Catch(Exception ex)
       {
         consolidateErrors +=  YourErrorDetails;
       }
   }
```